# android: how to add an entry in the lock screen settings?

Tags: android, android-screen

I want to create a custom screen lock/unlock widget and to configure it in the "standard" screen lock settings menu.

Is it possible programmaticaly to add new entries in the settings standard menus?

If yes, how? Can someone provide a code example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The lock screen runs in a totally separate sandbox environment which makes it inaccessible to third party apps. This is currently not supported by Android. Sorry.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
then the question would become, is it possible the make android use my
custom widget as default screen locker/unlocker? I want that android uses it even when the users want to do a "factory data reset"?
thnaks again.